# PHP using preg_match or regex as value for array_search or the key for array_keys_exist

Tags: php, regex, arrays, preg-replace

I was wondering if it was possible to use regex or `preg_match()` in `array_seach()` or `array_keys_exist`?

ie.
`array_keys_exist($array,"^\d+$")` to match all keys that are solely numeric characters

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't know whether it suits your needs exactly, but you should have a look at the [`preg_grep`](http://php.net/preg_grep) function, which will check an array of strings against a regex and return all matching array elements. You could do same with the keys, by using `preg_grep` on the return value of [`array_keys`](http://php.net/array_keys).

This is different from `array_search` / `array_key_exists` in the respect, that these stop after they have found a match, because there may only be one match. With regex on the other hand there may be many elements satisfying the condition, so `preg_grep` will return all of them.

Comment: I think `preg_grep` is exactly what the question asks for (to match all keys). And if you really only wanted a single result, then `current()` could be applied.

Comment: preg grep :) noice

Answer (score 1):

For that specific case you could use:

```
= array_filter(array_keys($array), "is_numeric")
```

For matching keys with other regular expressions you would need a custom callback.

(There would also be [`RecursiveRegexIterator`](http://php.net/RecursiveRegexIterator), but that's more syntax overhead.)

Comment: Better even `'ctype_digit'`. `is_numeric` typically is too much, unless you really want to match stuff like hex numbers and exponential notation.